# Want to capture grep counts for a command output

Tags: bash

I would like to count the occurrence of word ERROR by using command:-

```
mysql -B -u root -pxxxx -h abc -e show databases | grep -c "ERROR"
```

However my understanding says it should return 1 however it is returning it as O

Why ?

Also please let me know the significance of mysql -B and -e

Thanks,
Ruchir

Comment: Can you provide an example of grep's input?

Comment: To understanding the significance of `-B` and `-e`, try `man mysql` or `mysql --help`.

Answer (score 2):

Errors go to the standard error (stderr) by default, so you need to redirect it to standard output (via `2>&1`). In which case grep can process them:

```
mysql -B -u root -pxxxx -h abc -e show databases 2>&1 | grep -c "ERROR"
```

Comment: Or you can use  `|&` as a shortcut for ` 2>&1 |` (Bash 4.0)

Comment: Only be careful that multiple `ERROR` on a single line are counted as one.

Comment: Yes, it is better `grep -o "ERROR" | wc -l`.